# How to give witadmin execution rights to a dotnet application on IIS?

Tags: c#, .net, iis, execution

I have created a C# dotnet application, in which I run `witadmin` commands :

```
Process process = new() { StartInfo =
{
    FileName = "witadmin.exe",
    Arguments = $"exportgloballist {TfsCollectionArgument}",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
}};
process.Start();
var res = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

```
Process process = new() { StartInfo =
{
    FileName = "witadmin.exe",
    Arguments = $"importgloballist {TfsCollectionArgument} /f:{Path.Combine(System.AppContext.BaseDirectory, "globallistsToPost.xml")}",
    UseShellExecute = false,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    CreateNoWindow = true
}};
process.Start();
var res = await process.StandardOutput.ReadToEndAsync();
```

The code works perfectly on my computer: I can execute these `witadmin` commands directly from a CMD, and without having done anything special my application also has permission to execute these commands.

The problem is when I put my application on a server with IIS. `witadmin.exe` is in the PATH on the server, so I can run `witadmin.exe` (note that I am administrator). However when my application runs `witadmin.exe`, I get an error `you are not authorized to access [My collection]`.
How can I avoid this error? I think that my application should have the right to run `witadmin.exe`, as it is the case for the administrator role on the server, but how to give this authorization to my dotnet IIS application?
Thank you in advance, please tell me if I have not been clear on some points.

Comment: This is not about the "right to run witadmin.exe", but about the permissions granted to the **user** running witadmin.exe

Comment: In Windows you cannot claim "in the PATH" without saying clearly under which account. Note that such environment variables can be set at different levels and some accounts (like IIS default application pool identities) cannot see the one you set. Too much to learn https://halfblood.pro/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this solution, set ApplicationPool Identity as the Admin user:

1. In IIS Manager, select Application Pools.
2. From the list of application pools, right-click your website ApplicationPool and select Advanced Settings.
3. In the Process Model section, change the identity property to Custom account and enter the admin account.

[image]

Comment: It worked thank you so much!! I went by myself to step 3, but I used the default account "system" which did not have the same rights as admin. But with admin it’s okay. Be careful however for others who would read this answer, it adds security vulnerabilities, perhaps do not use this solution for a site accessible to the general public.